# Update ready for sale, not showing up in App Store under "Update" (6 days)

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

So I applied for an expedited review on the 8th of december and it was approved, processed and ready for sale on the 9th of December.

I have version 2.0.1 on my phone, and the version 2.0.2 is not showing up as an "Update" in app store. When going to app store it will show me the date I upgraded to 2.0.1 and shows that is the newest one.

If i then click on the cell to show more info, it takes me to my page listing 2.0.2 and all the correct details.

If I search my app on the store, it shows correct info 2.0.1, it is just everyone who already has my app, is not being promoted to update.

It has been 6 days, and Ive contacted ItunesConnect support, they tell me everything is fine on their end and if I have users who are having problems, to instruct them to call Store Support. So I told them its all 50,000 users who are having the issue, and they instructed me to inform 50,000 people to contact Store support.

So at this point Im all out of ideas.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, clearly someone needs a hug.

Comment: Lol someone down voted? Thats super lame. I think I am running into this same problem because it has been almost 24 hours since the update has changed to "Ready for Sale"

Comment: @thekenner33 it cant take a day to show up sometimes, if it doesnt show up by in another 24 hours, just increment the version number and resubmit, and it should work. Sometimes it looks like it just hangs up in the server somewhere.

Comment: I actually called the support line and they said there is probably something wrong, so they transferred me to some manager dude who resubmitted the update and it showed up after like 15 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes connect called me back after a few hours, they had spoken to Store support and there is an active bug they are trying to fix. They said this is a not a wide spread issue, but it is affecting many Devs.

They told me to sit and wait.

Edit

They never were able to fix it, after 7 days of error, I uploaded a new build, submitted for review, once approved, it kick started the process again, and was pushed correctly to the iTunes Servers.